# Android: add object to list if a certain field of the object doesn't exist in that list

Tags: android

I have an object called items, with this class:

```
      public class Items(){

       String item_id;
       String item_name

       public Items(){}

       public Items(String item_id , String item_name){

        this.item_id = item_id;
        this.item_name = item_name;


        }

        public String getItem_id(){

         return item_id;
        }

        public void setItem_id(){

         this.item_id = item_id;
        }

        public String getItem_name(){
         return item_name;
        }

        public void setItem_name(){

         this.item_name = item_name;  
        }


      }
```

Now I want to add this object to a `List`, but I want the object to be added only if (there is no other object with the same `item_id` in the list).

some thing like that:

```
     List<Items> item_list = new ArrayList():

     Items item = new Items();
     item.setItem_id("item_0001");


      if(/*list doesn't have an object with this id*/){

       item_list.add(item);
      }
```

I want to achieve this without the need to loop through the list each time I want to add a new item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essentially, there is no other way to do this without looping if you want to use an array-like data structure. Even class methods like List.contains() use iteration. You can use a Map like one of the other answers suggests. Alternately, you can use a Set if you don't want to modify your existing data structure.

```
List<Items> item_list = new ArrayList():
Set<String> item_set = new HashSet();

Items item = new Items();
item.setItem_id("item_0001");


 if(!item_set.contains(item.getItem_id()))
 {
   item_list.add(item);
   item_set.add(item.getItem_id())
 }
```

Comment: Yes this seems as the best thing to do. Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off with another data structure, a HashTable for example. There's no way of searching a List without looping (explicitly or implicitly) through it.

```
Map<String, Items> map = new HashMap<>();

 Items item = new Items();
 item.setItem_id("item_0001");

  if(!map.containsKey(items.getItem_id())){
      map.put(item.getItem_id(), item);
  }
```

Then later you can simply grab the values from the map:

```
List<Items> list = new ArrayList<Items>(map.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **equals** method. Let me show you with an example. `For e.g.` in my case i have `ProductListDataResponse` class. You just need to focus on **equals** method in this class and change your code according to your class.

for e.g.

```
 @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof ProductListDataResponse) {
            ProductListDataResponse productListDataResponse = (ProductListDataResponse) obj;
            return productId.equals(productListDataResponse.getProductId());
        } else return false;
    }
```

My ProductListDataResponse class:

```
public class ProductListDataResponse implements Serializable {

    @SerializedName("thumbnail_image")
    @Expose
    private String thumbnailImage;
    @SerializedName("actual_image")
    @Expose
    private String actualImage;
    @SerializedName("product_id")
    @Expose
    private String productId;
    @SerializedName("product_name")
    @Expose
    private String productName;
    @SerializedName("product_description")
    @Expose
    private String productDescription;
    @SerializedName("product_cost")
    @Expose
    private String productCost;
    @SerializedName("category_id")
    @Expose
    private String categoryId;
    @SerializedName("product_code")
    @Expose
    private String productCode;

    public ProductListDataResponse(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public ProductListDataResponse(String thumbnailImage, String actualImage, String productId, String productName,
                                   String productDescription, String productCost, String categoryId, String productCode) {
        this.thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage;
        this.actualImage = actualImage;
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
        this.productCost = productCost;
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    public String getThumbnailImage() {
        return thumbnailImage;
    }

    public void setThumbnailImage(String thumbnailImage) {
        this.thumbnailImage = thumbnailImage;
    }

    public String getActualImage() {
        return actualImage;
    }

    public void setActualImage(String actualImage) {
        this.actualImage = actualImage;
    }

    public String getProductId() {
        return productId;
    }

    public void setProductId(String productId) {
        this.productId = productId;
    }

    public String getProductName() {
        return productName;
    }

    public void setProductName(String productName) {
        this.productName = productName;
    }

    public String getProductDescription() {
        return productDescription;
    }

    public void setProductDescription(String productDescription) {
        this.productDescription = productDescription;
    }

    public String getProductCost() {
        return productCost;
    }

    public void setProductCost(String productCost) {
        this.productCost = productCost;
    }

    public String getCategoryId() {
        return categoryId;
    }

    public void setCategoryId(String categoryId) {
        this.categoryId = categoryId;
    }

    public String getProductCode() {
        return productCode;
    }

    public void setProductCode(String productCode) {
        this.productCode = productCode;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof ProductListDataResponse) {
            ProductListDataResponse productListDataResponse = (ProductListDataResponse) obj;
            return productId.equals(productListDataResponse.getProductId());
        } else return false;
    }
}
```

Now go to your class where you are adding the objects. Create the instance and pass the id. If Id exists it will return the position else it will return -1. When value is -1, it means value does not exist so save it now.

```
 for (int myCartIndex = 0; myCartIndex < myCartList.size(); myCartIndex++) {

                        MyCart myCart = myCartList.get(myCartIndex);
                        String productIdMyCart = myCart.getProductId();
                        ProductListDataResponse productListData = new ProductListDataResponse(productIdMyCart);
                        int index = productListDataResponseList.indexOf(productListData);

                        if (index == -1) {
                            //Add here your object.
                        }
}
```